# Can I get transform: scale() to cause overflow-scroll?

Tags: css

For mobile, I'm scaling a picture to it's full size. I'm doing this with transform scale since it results in the best frame-rate.

```
transition: transform 1s;
transform: translateY(0px) scale(2.43038);
```

(The scale is calculated in javascript)

The idea is to allow the user to scroll and zoom in the regular viewport, but when the image scales larger than the screen, no scroll is added. Can I somehow get the document width to expand with the image?

Comment: Make the original picture of the full size, and scaled downwards scale(0.4). Then transition it to scale(1).

Comment: It can trigger the scrollbar unless there is overflow:hidden set on container.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to wrap the image in an element with `overflow` defined to scroll, so the parent will scroll.

```css
body,html {
  height: 100%;
  }
div {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
img {
  transform: scale(20);
}
```

```html
<div><img src="http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/Simplest-Responsive-jQuery-Image-Lightbox-Plugin-simple-lightbox.jpg"></div>
```

Comment: The left part of the image is chopped off. You can add `transform-origin: 0 0` to solve that issue.